# How to store a string containing both single quote( ' ) and double quote( " ) in python

Tags: python, escaping

```
(+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","DD-Etopup",,"11/11/04,12:48:51+22" Hye! How's it going?)
```

I want to store this sms message in python as a string. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Triple quotes - this will allow embedded single and double-quotes without escape characters.

```
s = """(+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","DD-Etopup",,"11/11/04,12:48:51+22" Hye! How's it going?)"""
```

Comment: @JohnMachin: There's a minor flaw with that argument, if you want literal triple single-/double-quotes, you have no choice but to escape them still.  :)

Comment: Backslashes are the tool of last resort, because they're the only thing that can escape themselves. I forgot to mention triple quotes because I just use them for multi-line strings.

Answer (score 2):

Backslash escaping is the quick answer:

```
>>> '(+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","DD-Etopup",,"11/11/04,12:48:51+22" Hye! How\'s it going?)'
'(+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","DD-Etopup",,"11/11/04,12:48:51+22" Hye! How\'s it going?)'
>>> a = '(+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","DD-Etopup",,"11/11/04,12:48:51+22" Hye! How\'s it going?)'
>>> a.split(',')
['(+CMGL: 2', '"REC READ"', '"DD-Etopup"', '', '"11/11/04', '12:48:51+22" Hye! How\'s it going?)']
>>> a.split(',')[5]
'12:48:51+22" Hye! How\'s it going?)'
>>> len(a.split(',')[5])
34
```